# Auto Filter out Rows as soon as data is entered

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a google sheet where it automatically filters out the row as soon as a specific column has data input.

For example I have 5 columns but as soon as I enter a data in a cell under column #5 it would automatically filter out the entire row where the cell is.

Is this possible with a formula?

Thanks,

Comment: Please link a public example of a sheet or attach an image if at all possible. I am having a hard time understanding what you mean by filter out the entire row.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: What have you tried so far? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example with your data. How you want to filter it? Which criteria do you want to use to filter it?  You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.